# OpenCV warpPerspective - how to know destination image size?

Tags: opencv, perspective

Ok, I have to admit that I am a novice to OpenCV and that my MATLAB/lin. Algebra knowledge might be introducing a bias. But what I want to do is really simple, while I still did not manage to find an answer.

When trying to rectify an image (or part of an image) under a perspective transformation, you basically perform two steps (assuming you have the 4 points that define the distorted object):

1. find the transformation between some perfect rectangle and the distorted shape (in OpenCV, via `findHomography()` or `getPerspectiveTransform()` - why those two operate differently on the same points is another story, also frustrating); this gives us a matrix T.
2. apply the inverse of T to the initially distorted shape to transform it into a rectangle (in OpenCV, this is done with `warpPerspective()`).

Now, this last function (`warpPerspective()`) asks the user to specify the size of the destination image.

My question is how the users should know beforehand what that size would be. The low-level way of doing it is simply applying the transformation T to the corner points of the image in which the object is found, thus guaranteeing that you don't get out of the bounds with the newly transformed shape.
However, even if you take the matrix out of T and apply it manually to those points, the result looks weird.

Is there a way to do this in OpenCV? Thanks!

P.S. Below is some code:

```
float leftX, lowerY, rightX, higherY;   

float minX = std::numeric_limits<float>::max(), maxX = std::numeric_limits<float>::min(), minY = std::numeric_limits<float>::max(), maxY = std::numeric_limits<float>::min();

Mat value, pt;
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    switch(i)
    {
        case 0:
            pt = (Mat_<float>(3, 1) << 1.00,1.00,1.00);                         
            break;
        case 1:
            pt = (Mat_<float>(3, 1) << srcIm.cols,1.00,1.00);
            break;
        case 2:
            pt = (Mat_<float>(3, 1) << 1.00,srcIm.rows,1.00);
            break;
        case 3:
            pt = (Mat_<float>(3, 1) << srcIm.cols,srcIm.rows,1.00);
            break;
        default:
            cerr << "Wrong switch." << endl;
            break;
    }               
    value = invH*pt;    
    value /= value.at<float>(2);        
    minX = min(minX,value.at<float>(0));
    maxX = max(maxX,value.at<float>(0));
    minY = min(minY,value.at<float>(1));
    maxY = max(maxY,value.at<float>(1));
}
leftX = std::min<float>(1.00,-minX);
lowerY = std::min<float>(1.00,-minY);
rightX = max(srcIm.cols-minX,maxX-minX);
higherY = max(srcIm.rows-minY,maxY-minY);

warpPerspective(srcIm, dstIm, H, Size(rightX-leftX,higherY-lowerY), cv::INTER_CUBIC);
```

UPDATE: Perhaps my results do not look good because the matrix I'm using is wrong. As I cannot observe what's happening inside `getPerspectiveTransform()`, I cannot know how this matrix is computed, but it has some very small and very large values, which makes me think they are garbage.
This is the way I obtain the data from T:

```
for(int row=0;row<3;row++)
    for(int col=0;col<3;col++)
        T.at<float>(row,col) = ((float*)(H.data + (size_t)H.step*row))[col];
```

(Although the output matrix from `getPerspectiveTransform()` is 3x3, trying to access its values directly via `T.at<float>(row,col)` leads to a segmentation fault.)

Is this the right way to do it? Perhaps this is why the original issue arises, because I do not get the correct matrix...

Comment: Your low-level way seems correct to me. What do you mean by "the result looks weird"? Can you create a minimal example code to show the problem?

Comment: I mean that the coordinates I get are inside the original image (the result looks weird because I display an image, and it's only a part of it), which probably means that the matrix T is different from what I expect. It's normalized or something like that, not meant to operate on points directly...?

Comment: @Dobi I added some code on how I obtain the matrix values in the first place. Perhaps this is where the error arises...

Comment: Why not minimum example with which we can immediately reproduce your problem? :)

Answer (score 12):

If you know what the size of your image was before you call warpPerspective, then you can take the coordinates of its four corners and transform them with perspectiveTransform to see how they will turn out when they are transformed. Presumably, they will no longer form a nice rectangle, so you will probably want to compute the mins and maxs to obtain a bounding box. Then, the size of this bounding box is the destination size you want. (Also, don't forget to translate the box as needed if any of the corners dip below zero.) Here is a Python example that uses warpPerspective to blit a transformed image on top of itself.

```py
from typing import Tuple, Any
import cv2
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt
import math

# Input: a source image and perspective transform
# Output: a warped image and 2 translation terms
def perspective_warp(image:npt.NDArray[np.uint8], transform:npt.NDArray[Any]) -> Tuple[npt.NDArray[np.float32], int, int]:
    h, w = image.shape[:2]
    corners_bef = np.array([[0, 0], [w, 0], [w, h], [0, h]], dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    corners_aft = cv2.perspectiveTransform(corners_bef, transform)
    xmin = math.floor(corners_aft[:, 0, 0].min())
    ymin = math.floor(corners_aft[:, 0, 1].min())
    xmax = math.ceil(corners_aft[:, 0, 0].max())
    ymax = math.ceil(corners_aft[:, 0, 1].max())
    x_adj = math.floor(xmin - corners_aft[0, 0, 0])
    y_adj = math.floor(ymin - corners_aft[0, 0, 1])
    translate = np.eye(3)
    translate[0, 2] = -xmin
    translate[1, 2] = -ymin
    corrected_transform = np.matmul(translate, transform)
    return cv2.warpPerspective(image, corrected_transform, (math.ceil(xmax - xmin), math.ceil(ymax - ymin))), x_adj, y_adj

# Just like perspective_warp, but it also returns an alpha mask that can be used for blitting
def perspective_warp_with_mask(image:npt.NDArray[np.uint8], transform:npt.NDArray[Any]) -> Tuple[npt.NDArray[np.float32], npt.NDArray[np.float32], int, int]:
    mask_in = np.empty(image.shape[:2], dtype = np.uint8)
    mask_in.fill(255)
    output, x_adj, y_adj = perspective_warp(image, transform)
    mask, _, _ = perspective_warp(mask_in, transform)
    return output, mask, x_adj, y_adj

# alpha_blits src onto dest according to the alpha values in mask at location (x, y),
# ignoring any parts that do not overlap
def alpha_blit(dest:npt.NDArray[np.uint8], src:npt.NDArray[Any], mask:npt.NDArray[Any], x:int, y:int) -> None:
    dl = max(x, 0) # dest left
    dt = max(y, 0) # dest top
    sl = max(-x, 0) # source left
    st = max(-y, 0) # source top
    sr = max(sl, min(src.shape[1], dest.shape[1] - x)) # source right
    sb = max(st, min(src.shape[0], dest.shape[0] - y)) # source bottom
    dr = dl + sr - sl # dest right
    db = dt + sb - st # dest bottom

    # Crop and convert to floats as needed
    d = dest[dt:db, dl:dr].astype(np.float32)
    s = src[st:sb, sl:sr].astype(np.float32)
    m = mask[st:sb, sl:sr].reshape((sb - st, sr - sl, 1))

    # Combine alpha channel with the mask
    if s.shape[2] > 3:
        alpha = src[st:sb, sl:sr, 3:4]
        m = np.minimum(m, alpha)
        s = s[:,:,:3] # drop the alpha channel

    # Blit
    dest[dt:db, dl:dr] = (d * (255 - m) + s * m) / 255

# blits a perspective-warped src image onto dest
def perspective_blit(dest:npt.NDArray[np.uint8], src:npt.NDArray[np.uint8], transform:npt.NDArray[Any]) -> None:
    blitme, mask, x_adj, y_adj = perspective_warp_with_mask(src, transform)
    cv2.imwrite("blitme.png", blitme)
    alpha_blit(dest, blitme, mask, int(transform[0, 2] + x_adj), int(transform[1, 2] + y_adj))


# Read an input image
image:npt.NDArray[np.uint8] = cv2.imread('input.jpg')

# Make a perspective transform
h, w = image.shape[:2]
corners_in = np.array([[[0, 0]], [[w, 0]], [[w, h]], [[0, h]]], dtype=np.float32)
corners_out = np.array([[[100, 100]], [[300, -100]], [[500, 300]], [[-50, 500]]], dtype=np.float32)
transform = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(corners_in, corners_out)

# Blit the warped image on top of the original
perspective_blit(image, image, transform)
cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', image)
```

Example result:

[image: Left: input image. Right: output image]

Answer (score 2):

If the result looks wierd, it's maybe because your points aren't correctly set in getPerspectiveTransform. Your vector of points need to be in the right order (top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left).

But to answer your initial question, there's no such thing as the "optimal output size". You have to decide depending on what you want to do. Try and try to find the size that fits you.

EDIT :

If the problem comes from the transformation matrix, how do you create it ? A good way in openCV to do it is this :

```
vector<Point2f> corners;
corners.push_back(topleft);
corners.push_back(topright);
corners.push_back(bottomright);
corners.push_back(bottomleft);


// Corners of the destination image
// output is the output image, should be defined before this operation
vector<cv::Point2f> output_corner;
output_corner.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, 0));
output_corner.push_back(cv::Point2f(output.cols, 0));
output_corner.push_back(cv::Point2f(output.cols, output.rows));
output_corner.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, output.rows));

// Get transformation matrix
Mat H = getPerspectiveTransform(corners, output_corner);
```

Comment: The points are in the right order, because the image (or part of it) is correctly rectified, it's just being cropped unless you manually specify a large enough size for the output. Btw, it should really NOT be the case that the order as you propose should be fixed, as long as the sequence of points is always the same. And if trial and error is the only way to fit the output image to the proper size, I have to say that's quite ridiculous.

Comment: What do you want to do with the cropped image ? What is or should be the size of the detail you crop in the image ? That's things that cannot be detected automatically

Comment: If I understood correctly, it's not a question of scale, but of cropping. What I want to do is fit the image size to the dimensions of the rectified rectangle. There is a low-level way of doing this (see my exchange with Dobi), but that doesn't seem to work (mathematically, warping is simply multiplying every point by the transformation matrix T). So how do I know what the extent of that rectangle is?

Comment: You should post your code, to help us understand what's wrong

Comment: I edited the original post/question to include the code relating to transformation of corners.

Comment: Post edited, if this can't help you, I can't do anything for you. Good luck with your project

Comment: I wouldn't call "Try and try to find the size that fits you" very constructive.

Comment: can you tell how to get "topleft" and other??

Answer (score 1):

Only half a decade late!... I'm going to answer your questions one at a time:

**"My question is how the users should know beforehand what that size would be"**

You are actually just missing a step. I also recommend using `perspectiveTransform` just for the sake of ease over calculating the minimum and maximum X's and Y's yourself.

So once you have calculated the minimum X and Y, recognize that those can be negative. If they are negative, it means your image will be cropped. To fix this, you create a translation matrix and then correct your original homography:

```
Mat translate = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);
translate.at<CV_64F>(2, 0) = -minX;
translate.at<CV_64F>(2, 1) = -minY;
Mat corrected_H = translate * H;
```

Then the calculation for the destination size is just:

```
Size(maxX - minX, maxY - minY)
```

although also note that you'll want to convert `minX`, `maxX`, `minY`, and `maxY` to integers.

**"As I cannot observe what's happening inside getPerspectiveTransform(), I cannot know how this matrix is computed"**

https://github.com/opencv/opencv

That's the source code for OpenCV. You can definitely observe what's happening inside `getPerspectiveTransform`.

Also this: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html

The `getPerspectiveTransform` doesn't have great documentation on what they're doing, but the `findHomography` function does. I'm pretty sure `getPerspectiveTransform` is just the simple case when you have exactly the minimum number of points required to solve for 8 parameters (4 pairs of points i.e. the corners).