# OpenCV Android extract match Mat after feature detection

Tags: android, opencv

I want to extract the part of the image that matches my reference image.
I try to transform the image using the Calib3d.findHomography method.
When i have done this i use Imgproc.warpPerspective to do the transformation but with no good results. Do i miss something here?
Do i need to do something with perspectiveTransform? I have tried this but without any luck so far.

Here is my findSceneCorners method:

```
 private void findSceneCorners(Mat src) {
    mFeatureDetector.detect(src, mSceneKeypoints);
    mDescriptorExtractor.compute(src, mSceneKeypoints, mSceneDescriptors); 
    mDescriptorMatcher.match(mSceneDescriptors, mReferenceDescriptors, mMatches);

    List<DMatch> matchesList = mMatches.toList();
    if (matchesList.size() < 4) {
        // There are too few matches to find the homography.
        return;
    }

    List<KeyPoint> referenceKeypointsList =
            mReferenceKeypoints.toList();
    List<KeyPoint> sceneKeypointsList =
            mSceneKeypoints.toList();

    // Calculate the max and min distances between keypoints.
    double maxDist = 0.0;
    double minDist = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for(DMatch match : matchesList) {
        double dist = match.distance;
        if (dist < minDist) {
            minDist = dist;
        }
        if (dist > maxDist) {
            maxDist = dist;
        }
    }

    // The thresholds for minDist are chosen subjectively
    // based on testing. The unit is not related to pixel
    // distances; it is related to the number of failed tests
    // for similarity between the matched descriptors.
    if (minDist > 50.0) {
        // The target is completely lost.
        // Discard any previously found corners.
        mSceneCorners.create(0, 0, mSceneCorners.type());
        return;
    } else if (minDist > 20.0) {
        // The target is lost but maybe it is still close.
        // Keep any previously found corners.
        return;
    }


    // Identify "good" keypoints based on match distance.
    ArrayList<Point> goodReferencePointsList =
            new ArrayList<Point>();
    ArrayList<Point> goodScenePointsList =
            new ArrayList<Point>();

    double maxGoodMatchDist = 1.75 * minDist;
    for(DMatch match : matchesList) {
        if (match.distance < maxGoodMatchDist) {
           goodReferencePointsList.add(
                   referenceKeypointsList.get(match.trainIdx).pt);
           goodScenePointsList.add(
                   sceneKeypointsList.get(match.queryIdx).pt);
        }
    }

    if (goodReferencePointsList.size() < 4 ||
            goodScenePointsList.size() < 4) {
        // There are too few good points to find the homography.
        return;
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "Match found");

    MatOfPoint2f goodReferencePoints = new MatOfPoint2f();
    goodReferencePoints.fromList(goodReferencePointsList);

    MatOfPoint2f goodScenePoints = new MatOfPoint2f();
    goodScenePoints.fromList(goodScenePointsList);

    homography = Calib3d.findHomography(goodReferencePoints, goodScenePoints);

    Mat quad = new Mat(mReferenceImage.size(), CvType.CV_32F);
    Imgproc.warpPerspective(src, quad, homography, quad.size());
    objectDetectedListener.objectDetected(quad);

}
```

Comment: [This](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html) is the tutorial that OpenCV suggest, have you tried it? It sould help

Comment: Well i already have working code what does just that. Drawing a line around the found object. But what i'm trying to achieve is to extract that part of the image that matches into a new Mat object.

Comment: I don't have OpenCV installed on this computer, I suggest you to display the images, maybe you will figure out what is going on. I will give you an answare for tomorow if nobody else will answare meanwhile

Comment: [This](https://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/) is what i want to achieve except i'm not using canny but feature detection. And the quad would be based on the template image.

Comment: Look at [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18122444/1360570), maybe it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `WARP_INVERSE_MAP` as the flag of `warpPerspective` as: `Imgproc.warpPerspective(src, quad, homography, quad.size(),WARP_INVERSE_MAP);`.

I have not used exactly your code, but just the part after homography, and i have seen that the image was warped in the mirror, not as we wanted (use a bigger display image to see exactly what's there). In fact, on the page you posted, with the 10-card, it is used that flag, sorry that I have not thought of mentioning this earlier.

Comment: Thanks thedarkside ofthemoon this works just perfectly.