# Align normal of plane to camera

Tags: camera, alignment, projection, perspective, plane

I use a perspective projection camera and need to align a 3D plane so that it is facing the camera. I believe it has something to do with aligning the normal to the ray projected from the camera to the plane, but I'm not sure. I'm not too good at 3D maths so I don't really know how to go about doing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html) is an explanation for calibration, I think [this](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~ramani/cmsc828d/lecture9.pdf) would also help you. If you are trying to do it, I would recommend OpenCV.

[Homography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography_%28computer_vision%29) is another way to do it (also existent in OpenCV)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21087804/1360570) is another link which you can use, if you know a little OpenCV